# JS JQuery Highlight Plugin toUpperCase not a function, causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, highlight

I am trying to edit the jQuery hightlight plug in to highlight multiple words.  It works great until you hit the space bar, then it causes FF to freeze in an infinite loop.

FireBug reports that .toUpperCase is not a function, but when I change the same code back, so it is not altering an array element, it's fine, but does not highlight the two words, only the first one.  When the space bar is hit all highlighting goes away.

Here is the what I have so far. The code in question is in the return this.each(function(){}) block at the end:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
    var skip = 0;

    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            var spannode = document.createElement('span');
            spannode.className = 'highlight';
            var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
            var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
            var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
            spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
            middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
            skip = 1;
        }
    } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
            i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
        }
    }

    return skip;    
}
return this.each(function() {
    var parts = pat.split(' ');
    console.log(parts);
    for (var i in parts) {
        innerHighlight(this, parts[i].toUpperCase());
        console.log("parts["+i+"] >> " + parts[i]);
    }
});
};
```

Here is the console output in FireBug:

```
["guy"]                            jquery...ht-3.js (line 46)
parts[0] >> guy                    jquery...ht-3.js (line 49)
parts[i].toUpperCase is not a function
    [Break On This Error] innerHighlight(this, parts[i].toUpperCase());
                                   jquery...ht-3.js (line 48)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest using CSS `text-transform: uppercase;` rather than actually converting the string to upper case.

Comment: The only reason its transforming in JS is to compare the string to highlight.  The text the user sees is never changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh dear. That plugin is using an unfiltered `for...in` loop to iterate over an array. **[That's bad:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Parameters)**

> `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where index
>   order is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
>   integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties.  There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a `for` loop with a numeric index when iterating
>   over arrays where the order of access is important.
>
> Where only the properties of the object should be considered, a
>   `hasOwnProperty` check should be performed to ensure that only
>   properties of the object and not inherited properties are used
>   (`propertyIsEnumerable` can also be used but is not intuitive).

---

So, change this:

```
for (var i in parts) {
    innerHighlight(this, parts[i].toUpperCase());
    console.log("parts["+i+"] >> " + parts[i]);
}
```

to this:

```
for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    innerHighlight(this, parts[i].toUpperCase());
    console.log("parts["+i+"] >> " + parts[i]);
}
```

Comment: yea, first time I've tried that type of for, google results said it was equivalent to php's for..each, unless i read it wrong.  changed it to the other type, still causing FF to hang.

Comment: Does it still complain about "`.toUpperCase()` is not a function?" If so, what is the value of `parts[i]` at that time? (Switch the order of the `console.log` and `innerHighlight` function calls to see.)

Comment: Nope, that got rid of the toUpperCase issue.  Now, it just hangs, but is timing out.  Both before and after values are the same.

Comment: It's only hanging when the space is the last char of the string. It hangs for about 10-15 seconds then prompts to end script.  (.=space) So foo. hangs but after it gets "over it" foo.bar.. works fine.  When the dialog comes up it says that the for(var i=0; i < node.childNodes[i], pat) loop in the else if block is making it mad.

Comment: Would you mind putting together a minimal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem? Does it only happen in Firefox (and which version)?

Comment: Sure give me a few...Right now I'm dev'ing in FF 7 on linux with IE plugins.. I will try the IE engine out after I put together something on jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Here is the link, I am having trouble getting the fake results to show in the div...trying to rush since I'm leaving early today...  I hate to submit this link while I'm still working on it, but its got to be something stupid where I'm creating the json object... http://jsfiddle.net/guyfromfl/Ax9ng/

Comment: I think I solved it.  I ended up trimming the string before sending it to the innerHighlight method, and it seems to be running fine now.

Comment: Good to hear, sorry I couldn't be of more assistance along the way.